# How to tell between two exactly similar monitors connected to the computer using WMI or Win32API

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I'm writing a monitoring agent which monitors all screens connected to the pc.
When one of the screens is disconnected, I get an email notification which tells me exactly which screen it was.

The problem is that I can't find a persistent way to tell between the 2 screens because they are exactly alike - same vendor and model.

I need to find a Unique Id of the each device which will persist through Reboots and Power loss.
I couldn't find anything unique on windows device manager. Tried to go with WMI or Win32API but so far no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Windows Vista you can use the [`WmiMonitorID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, Try the  `SerialNumberID` property.